# Magento 2 : i'it possible can enter the product subtotal price forecast based on quantity?

Tags: magento, magento2

On the product page I would like to show the subtotal price based on the quantity entered before clicking on "add to cart"

in practice I would like to draw the price of the product and multiply it by the quantity and print it below or instead of the price near the "add to cart" button

I am not a developer and I don't know the code

Comment: Are you asking for code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, if is semple yes